# Remove column from AspNetUsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created a database context. I would like remove some columns in tables `AspNetUsers` e.g. `PhoneNumber`, `PhoneNumberConfirmed` because it isn't necessary in my application.

```
namespace TestTest.Infrastuctures
{
    public class TestContext:IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public TestContext()
            : base("TestContext")
        {

        }
        public static TestContext Create()
        {
            return new TestContext();
        }
        public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    }

    public class ApplicationUserEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserEntityTypeConfiguration()
        {
            Ignore(p => p.PhoneNumber);
            Ignore(p => p.PhoneNumberConfirmed);
            Ignore(p => p.EmailConfirmed);
            Ignore(p => p.TwoFactorEnabled);

        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine,but have not removed the selected columns in AspNetUsers.[image]

Any help or suggestion is welcome.

**Update**

This code solved my problem:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            var user = modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>();
            user.Ignore(u => u.EmailConfirmed);
            user.Ignore(u => u.PhoneNumber);
            user.Ignore(u => u.PhoneNumberConfirmed);

            var identityUserRole = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>();
            identityUserRole.HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleId });

            var identityUserLogin = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>();
            identityUserLogin.HasKey(l => new { l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey, l.UserId });

            var claims = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>();

       }
```

Comment: Your update is basically what my answer says.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do this but not necessarily with the `EntityTypeConfiguration` method. Instead try overriding the `OnModelCreating` method in your context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
        .Ignore(p => p.PhoneNumber)
        .Ignore(p => p.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
        .Ignore(p => p.EmailConfirmed)
        .Ignore(p => p.TwoFactorEnabled);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove any of the built-in properties. They're there to support Identity functionality. Whether or not you're actually requiring email confirmation, it's valuable to know whether the email has been confirmed or not.

Adding additional properties works just like any other entity would. Create a class, if you haven't already, that inherits from IdentityUser, and add whatever properties you like to that.

Answer (score -2):

Go to the class for ApplicationUser, delete the attributes for PhoneNumber, PhoneNumberConfirmed.

Add migration and then update your database.

Comment: Those properties come from a class inside the Identity framework and are not editable without downloading the entire thing from Githugb and compiling it yourself.